# what is the next tag after the specific tag in html using xpath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have this HTML code:

```
<a name="apple"></a>
<h3> header1 </h3>
<p> some text </p>
<p> some text1 </p>
<a name="orange"></a>
<h3> header2 </h3>
<p> some text 2 </p>
```

I want to retrieve the text after the header tag, using code like this:

```
for header in tree.iter('h3'):
 paragraph = header.xpath('(.//following::p)[1]')
 if (header.text=="apple"):
    print "%s: %s" % (header.text, paragraph[0].text)
```

It doesn't work when I have more than one `<p>` tag. How can I find out how many `<p>` tags I have after my heading and retrieve all of them?

I use python 2.7 and xpath.

Comment: Do you want all `<p>` after each `<h3>` *until* the next `<h3>`? or everything after the first `<h3>`, including the 2nd "header2"?

Comment: @paul t. all <p> after each <h3>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to use `lxml`'s  ([`itersibling()`](http://lxml.de/api.html#iteration)), work on the siblings, not  descendants, and then work on descendants of these siblings if necessary.

You can try something like this

```
>>> for heading in root.iter("h3"):
...     print "----", heading
...     for sibling in heading.itersiblings():
...         if sibling.tag == 'h3':
...             break
...         print sibling
... 
---- <Element h3 at 0x1880470>
<Element p at 0x18800b0>
<Element p at 0x1880110>
<Element a at 0x1880170>
---- <Element h3 at 0x1880050>
<Element p at 0x18801d0>
>>>
```

If you want to use XPath, you can use EXSLT's [set extension](http://www.exslt.org/set/index.html) that's available in `lxml` (through the `"http://exslt.org/sets"` namespace, and the idea is roughly the same as above:

- select all siblings (`following-sibling::*`),
- but exlude (`set:difference()`) the next `<h3>` sibling (`following-sibling::h3`) and (`|` XPath operator) all its following siblings also (`following-sibling::h3/following-sibling::*`).

That could be used like this:

```
>>> following_siblings_untilh3 = lxml.etree.XPath("""
...         set:difference(
...             following-sibling::*,
...             (following-sibling::h3|following-sibling::h3/following-sibling::*))""",
...         namespaces={"set": "http://exslt.org/sets"})
>>> 
>>> for heading in root.iter("h3"):
...     print "----", heading
...     for e in following_siblings_noth3(heading): print e
... 
---- <Element h3 at 0x1880470>
<Element p at 0x18800b0>
<Element p at 0x1880110>
<Element a at 0x1880170>
---- <Element h3 at 0x1880050>
<Element p at 0x18801d0>
>>>
```

I'm sure it can be simplified. (I haven't found a `following-sibling-or-self::h3`...)